# HttpsURLConnection + Cloudflare API FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, android, https, filenotfoundexception

I'm trying to create an app for android and I'm trying to read my stats from my CloudFlare Dashboard.
The strange thing is that if my code reaches the line `ins = con != null ? con.getInputStream() : null;` It will say "FileNotFoundException".
The headers are set as they should. Here is the quote from the CF API Documentation:

> The dashboard view provides both totals and timeseries data for the given zone and time period across the entire CloudFlare network.
>   GET /zones/:zone_identifier/analytics/dashboard
>   - https://api.cloudflare.com/#zone-analytics-dashboard

Some parameters are optional, I double checked my data already and it works fine in Postman.

I tried to use http but CF doesn't allow it.

My code:

```
class JsonRequest extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
private String readStream(InputStream is) {
    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bo = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int i = is.read();
        while (i != -1) {
            bo.write(i);
            i = is.read();
        }
        return bo.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return "";
    }
}

protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    URL myurl = null;
    try {
        myurl = new URL(params[0]);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    HttpsURLConnection con = null;
    try {
        con = (HttpsURLConnection)myurl.openConnection();
        con.setRequestProperty("X-Auth-Email", "email");
        con.setRequestProperty("X-Auth-Key", "key");
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0 ( compatible ) ");
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept","*/*");
        con.setDoOutput(false);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    InputStream ins = null;
    try {
        ins = con != null ? con.getInputStream() : null; // FileNotFoundException
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(ins);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(isr);
    try {
        in.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return readStream(ins);
    }
}
```